# VBA for duplicate rows

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I have a sheet of columns.
I want to compare data in multiple columns, and return a flag in another column to indicate rows that are duplicates. I found a little code online which was meant for checking one column of data, and have so far been unsuccessful in being able to tweek it for multiple columns. The final code will need to look at specific columns which I will define later however for the moment say the sheet is as follows:
StaffNumber CallType
1   A
2   B
1   A
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
8   H
1   A
2   C
1   Z
6   P

The Col A is labelled Staff Number. Col B is labelled CallType. In Col C I want the flag to be entered against the row.

My Code is as follows:

Sub DuplicateIssue()

```
Dim last_StaffNumber As Long
Dim last_CallType As Long

Dim match_StaffNumber As Long
Dim match_CallType As Long

Dim StaffNumber As Long
Dim CallType As Long

last_StaffNumber = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
last_CallType = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

For StaffNumber = 1 To last_StaffNumber
For CallType = 1 To last_CallType

    'checking if the Staff Number cell is having any item, skipping if it is blank.
        If Cells(StaffNumber, 1) <> " " Then

        'getting match index number for the value of the cell
            match_StaffNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(StaffNumber, 1), Range("A1:A" & last_StaffNumber), 0)

            If Cells(CallType, 2) <> " " Then

            match_CallType = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(CallType, 2), Range("B1:B" & last_CallType), 0)

                'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
                If StaffNumber <> match_StaffNumber And CallType <> match_CallType Then
                    'Printing the label in the column C
                    Cells(StaffNumber, 3) = "Duplicate"
                End If
            End If
        End If
Next
Next
```

End Sub

My problem is that only when Col 1 is a duplicate will the macro enter "Duplicate" into Col C, and it is not checking if the value of Col B is also the same. 
Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub showDuplicateRows()
    Const SHEET_NAME    As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LAST_COL      As Long = 3 ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Update last column
    Const FIRST_ROW     As Long = 2
    Const FIRST_COL     As Long = 1
    Const DUPE          As String = "Duplicate"
    Const CASE_SENSITIVE As Byte = 1                    'Matches UPPER & lower

    Dim includedColumns As Object
    Set includedColumns = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With includedColumns
        .Add 1, ""  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 1 as dupe criteria
        .Add 3, ""  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 3 as dupe criteria
    End With
    Dim searchRng       As Range
    Dim memArr          As Variant
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim unique          As String
    Dim totalRows       As Long
    Dim totalCols       As Long
    Dim totalURCols     As Long
    Dim valDict         As Object
    Set valDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If CASE_SENSITIVE = 1 Then
        valDict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        valDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
        totalRows = .UsedRange.Rows.Count               'get last used row on sheet
        totalURCols = .UsedRange.Columns.Count          'get last used col on sheet
        Set searchRng = .Range( _
                                .Cells(FIRST_ROW, FIRST_COL), _
                                .Cells(totalRows, LAST_COL) _
                                )
        If LAST_COL < totalURCols Then
                        .Range( _
                                .Cells(FIRST_ROW, LAST_COL + 1), _
                                .Cells(FIRST_ROW, totalURCols) _
                                ).EntireColumn.Delete   'delete any extra columns
        End If
    End With

    memArr = searchRng.Resize(totalRows, LAST_COL + 1)  'entire range with data to mem

    For i = 1 To totalRows                              'each row, without the header
        For j = 1 To LAST_COL                           'each col
            If includedColumns.exists(j) Then
                unique = unique & searchRng(i, j)       'concatenate values on same row
            End If
        Next
        If valDict.exists(unique) Then                  'check if entire row exists
            memArr(i, LAST_COL + 1) = DUPE              'if it does, flag it in last col
        Else
            valDict.Add Key:=unique, Item:=i            'else add it to the dictionary
        End If
        unique = vbNullString
    Next
    searchRng.Resize(totalRows, LAST_COL + 1) = memArr  'entire memory back to the sheet
End Sub
```

.

Result:

[image: DuplicateRows.jpg]

Comment: Legend!!Thankyou Paul

Comment: Just A quick question. Where you have EntireColumn.Delete   'delete any extra columns, I would just enter the columns, say: EntireColumn.Delete(4,5,6)   to delete col 4, 5 and 6 from the comparison ??

Comment: I'm glad it helped. For the line with ".EntireColumn.Delete" - that line removes any, and all columns beyond LAST_COL. So, if you set LAST_COL = 5 and your sheet has a total of 9 used columns it will delete columns 6 to 9

Comment: Is there any way to specify select columns to be excluded from the comparison? Say I want to compare on col 1, 2 & 5, but not 3 & 4?

Comment: Sure. But you may want to consider specifying the columns to BE included - I'm assuming you'll probably end up with about 20 columns, and your criteria to identify duplicate rows might be based on 3 to 5. Either way I can modify it so it will take a list of headers names (or column numbers) and exclude them all, or include the ones in the list and exclude the rest (a shorter list is best)

Comment: Include a list of Column numbers would be the best dude. Cheers

Comment: ok, so you want to be able to provide a list of sheet numbers to be included (not excluded)

Comment: Yes mate. I would specify the columns to include in the comparison.

Comment: Hi paul, I was wondering if you could help me with your code here. I am now trying to covert it for use in Visual Basic, however it is throwing me a COMException was handled error on the "If includedColumns.exists(j) Then" line. Also It is telling me that "Variable "Unique" is used before it has been assigned a value". The code you gave me is basically the same.

Comment: I'm not sure about the differences between VBA and VB, but you can fix the "unique" issue by adding this "unique = vbNullString" before the first IF (`If CASE_SENSITIVE = 1 Then`). The COMException it's specific to VB and Icaused by the external reference to the "Scripting.Dictionary" object - you may need to ask in VB how to use or import a "Scripting.Dictionary" object (not necessarily related to VBA). VB may already have an internal dictionary structure, without the need to import one

Comment: Hi Paul,I found a little bit here http://www.vbasic.net/dictionary-data-type-visual-basic/ , have updated the code accordingly, however the "Then" is still throwing the error

Comment: strange; it looks like it should work the same way. The "Exists" method should work as well; Try watching the the "includedColumns" object (its count, and what items it contains), the "j" and the what the return type of `includedColumns.exists(j)` is (hard to guess without VB)

Comment: Looking at this old bit of code, the same thing is happening, and it does not use a scripting dictionary, so I may put this up for some advice and see what I get. I will then attempt to implement the fix for the following code with yours and see How I go:

Comment: what do you mean? (why not?)